# First Condition IF can't run, cause can;t Get data on View code

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker, mariadb

I have code to filter by dates, I have 2 condition,

1. **First condition: *get 'tanggal' from date picker on view***
2. Second condition: variable 'tanggal' isNull

However, the code only runs the second condition, even though the condition variable date is given

This is the code:

**View:**

```
.... some code ....
   <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                </div>

                <form name="Filter" method="POST">
                                    From:
                                    <input type="date" name="dateFrom" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="FILTER" />
                                </form>

.... some code ....

                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ((array)$getDepartDetail as $us) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $us->Name ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->NIK ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->gender ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->PositionDesc ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->Shift ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->tgl ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $us->Attendance ?></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo site_url('data_detail/detail_datas/vieworc/' . $us->NIK); ?>">Detail</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>

.... some code ....
```

*When I fill in the form and submit it, the date on the form still shows today's date, not in accordance with what I entered*
**Model:**

```
.... some code ....
    public function get_allDprtDetail($DepartmentID)
        {
           if(isset($_GET['dateFrom'])){
    $tgl = date(strtotime($_POST['dateFrom']));
    
            $datas = "
            SELECT DISTINCT
            .... some code ....
        FROM
            emp00003
            LEFT JOIN v_dvc0004_test ON emp0003.NIK = v_dvc0004_test.NIK 
                    AND DATE(v_dvc0004_test.Enroll) = '$tgl'
             .... some code ....
        
        ";}
            else{
                $datas = "
                SELECT DISTINCT
                .... some code ....
            }
                $query = $this->db->query($datas);
                return $query->result()

;}
```

*in ***model code*** cant get variabel from datepicket in ***view code****

*Controller :*

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class departmentDetail extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $model = 'detailDprt/detailDepartmentModel';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model($model, 'detailDepartmentModel');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['getDepartDetail'] = $this->detailDepartmentModel->get_allDprtDetail();
        $this->load->view('total_emp/allDepartmentView', $data);
    }

    public function detailDprt($DepartmentID)
    {
        $data['getDepartDetail'] = $this->detailDepartmentModel->get_allDprtDetail($DepartmentID);
        $data['getTitleDprt'] = $this->detailDepartmentModel->get_titleDprt($DepartmentID);
        $this->load->view('total_emp/allDepartmentView', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the controller code ?

Comment: @DaffaAkbari okey wait, i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send the date to the model.

you need the controller to send the var to the model.
I assume you will use the detailDprt controller for your submit form.
something like this.

```
public function detailDprt($DepartmentID)
    {
        $dateFilter = date("n/j/Y", strtotime($this->input->post(dateForm)));

        $data['getDepartDetail'] = $this->detailDepartmentModel->get_allDprtDetail($DepartmentID, $dateFilter);
        $data['getTitleDprt'] = $this->detailDepartmentModel->get_titleDprt($DepartmentID);
        $this->load->view('total_emp/allDepartmentView', $data);
    }
```

and change your post model with something like this.

```
public function get_allDprtDetail($DepartmentID, $dateFilter)
        {
           if(isset($dateFilter)){
    
    
            $datas = "
            SELECT DISTINCT
            .... some code ....
        FROM
            emp00003
            LEFT JOIN v_dvc0004_test ON emp0003.NIK = v_dvc0004_test.NIK 
                    AND DATE(v_dvc0004_test.Enroll) = '$dateFilter'
             .... some code ....
        
        ";}
            else{
                $datas = "
                SELECT DISTINCT
                .... some code ....
            }
                $query = $this->db->query($datas);
                return $query->result()

;}
```

obviously, you need to change the form method to call the detailDprt controller.